# Confusion about lifetime annotation on a traits associated type

Tags: rust

When I was trying to implement some trait for a reference type with a lifetime, I found the following [code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=43501e9658ce3e113a9a2252bf1b1d03) doesn't compile when the associated type `R` is uncommented but compiles when removing it.

```rust
trait Foo {
    // type R;
    fn foo(&mut self);
}

struct B;

impl<'a> Foo for B
where
    &'a B: 'a,
{
    // type R = &'a u8;
    fn foo(&mut self) {
        println!("=====");
    }
}
fn main() {
    let b = &mut B;
    b.foo();
}
```

What's the meaning of the `where` clause?

Furthermore, when I tried to uncomment the code, then the compiler complains about [E0207](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error_codes/E0207.html), why didn't the compiler error on the previous code?

Comment: The code you shared does not compile.

Comment: Oh your link is to the second version. The where clause does nothing.

Comment: In fact the where clause is unrelated to the problem alltogether, removing it still shows the same behavior as with it.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Why compiler don't compile about lifetime parameter not constrained after removing where clause? It seems not meet the [criterias](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error_codes/E0207.html)

Comment: I'm trying to implement a trait with associated type R with a lifetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more context, the code looks like it's trying to work around the lack of Generic Associated Types. Since they're available as of Rust 1.65, you can drop the where clause and add a generic lifetime param to the R associated type.

```
trait Foo {
    type R<'a>;
    fn foo(&mut self);
}

struct B;

impl Foo for B
{
    type R<'a> = &'a u8;
    fn foo(&mut self){println!("=====");}
}

fn main() {
    let b = &mut B;
    b.foo();
}
```